# How do I access init parameters from a JSP2 tag file?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, init-parameters

I'm trying to create a jsp tag file but it fails to compile when I try to use `pageContext.getServletConfig().getInitParameter("myInitParam")`

I'm using tomcat and when I try to view a page including the file I get a jasper compile error pageContext cannot be resolved. I've also tried just using `getInitParameter` but it fails also. I can use the request object so I know everything else is fine.

Does anyone know a way to access init parameters set in the web.xml from a jsp tag file, preferably from within a scriptlet?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the trick is to use one of the implicit objects, in this case config or application depending on the init-parameters scope. 
they are list at http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/11/14/tagfiles.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the request rather than the pageContext? Or just off the servlet itself:

```
getInitParameter("myInitParam");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you extending the [TagSupport](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagSupport.html) class?

If so, this class has a member named `pageContext`, the Tag interface declares a method `setPageContext(PageContext pc)`, which the docs state

> This method is invoked by the JSP page implementation object prior to doStartTag().

So you should be able to reference `this.pageContext` fine - unless you are extending a different class?

Answer (score 0):

```
application.getInitParameter("<Name>");
```